# How do you represent a place in an XML document to a user?

Tags: java, xml

I'm parsing an XML document with code similar to the code shown below.  After the code has been parsed into a `Node` tree, it's then processed as a configuration for my program.  For any number of reasons there may be an error in this configuration which will need to be reported back to the user.

My program is operating on the assumption that all errors can be attributed to a single node (even if that node is only the point at which the error was detected).

If this configuration was simply read from a flat file (line by line), the error reported to the user could be something like `Error at line number 42 ...`, but because the error is only detected after the configuration has been parsed into an abstract Node tree, the location of the error in the config file has been lost.

How can I represent the location of the erroneous node to the user bearing in mind that these config files can be pretty big?

**Parsing Code**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(inputDocument);
```

Comment: Do you mean that the error is not in the XML structure itself, but that the value in the xml is invalid as input for your program?

Comment: Exactly yes.  The assumption is that the code above succeeds, if not that will be handled differently.

Comment: would you like to report an XPath to the incorrect location? Line numbers might or might not be appropriate. It depends on the formatting of the XML itself. What if the XML is not formatted at all?

Comment: How about telling them the name of the configuration item and the value that makes it invalid (along with the range of possible correct values)? If you know it's invalid, you can surely report the name to the user so they know what to correct. "Invalid value -2 for FontSize; values should be positive, and between 4 and 48".

Comment: That's great where "font-size" is used once.  What if it's used 30 - 40 times.  What if the error is "foo-bar-widget missing attribute 'name'". There is nothing for the user to search the file on.  It must have a reference back to file to direct the usere were to look.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is not in the XML structure but that the value in the xml is invalid as input for your program, then it would make most sense to make domain specific reports to the user.

Imagine your user is a claims adjuster.  Which of the following error reports should you give him.

1. "Data Error at line 3253 of data.xml";
2. some XPath expression;
3. "Invalid Settlement Offer wrt Peterson Claim, offer should not exceed statory limit"

Cases 1 and 2 are undecipherable.  Case 3 is actionable.

Comment: couling could use this googled up example: http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/xml-dom-2/
and return both the file + line number (1) *and* (3), which I think would be best.

Comment: @owlstead can you put that in as an awnser as it looks to be what I need. In this context the "user" would be a sysadmin, we're talking more about a serverside application config than an end user input. Keeping the error message meaningful is allways a challenge, but it must refer back to the config file. The error may wish to report the missing attribute stating the name, hence "Peterson Claim" is the very thing that is missing.